# How to give a variable of my script sh to my script SQL?

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm looking for to pass a variable of my bash script, in my SQL query file and I can not.

**Here is the latest version into my script.sh:**

```
user = "USEREXAMPLE"

mysql –root -proot –h localhost -A -e "set @user=${user};" > "add.sql";
```

**into my add.sql:**

```
CREATE USER ', @user ,’@‘localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ', @user ,';
```

*Request desired after this :*

> CREATE USER USEREXEMPLE@localhost IDENTIFIED BY USEREXEMPLE;

Comment: Your variable is not properly defined. It should be `user="USEREXAMPLE"`. Spaces are not allowed before and after equal signs.

Answer (score 1):

Create your file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

user="USEREXAMPLE"

echo "CREATE USER $user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY $user;" >add.sql
```

Then user add.sql in your mysql command.

Comment: Have you considered using a heredoc instead?

Comment: Sure why not?  But when the amount of text is small, I prefer doing it like that.